# log4j2 configuration change from size based to time based

Tags: log4j, log4j2

We're looking to change our size based trigger to time based trigger policy (every 5 minutes). But our configuration looks very different from the current log4j2. Here's our current configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
```

If I change it to this, I'm not sure if it'll work or if I'm missing anything?

```
log4j.appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
log4j.appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
log4j.appender.rolling.fileName = spark.log
log4j.appender.rolling.filePattern = ${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 5
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
```

Comment: Your old config is Log4j 1.x config. Since you are converting to a Log4j2 config, use the XML, JSON or YAML format, since they are much less verbose and error-prone.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz this is interesting, we're on `2.17.1` and the log4j 1.x config works

Comment: There is a configuration factory in `log4j-1.2-api` that converts old configs on the fly (it's enabled if `log4j1.compatibility` is set to `true` or `log4j.configuration` points to a Log4j 1.2 config file), but more complex configurations need a native Log4j2 config.